# Firebase Realtime Database geting User by Email/Name in Android with Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Screenshot of the database]

I want to get a User or just a User UID via email or name. Tried to write the query, but I'm getting all users and then iterating through them and then getting the user but I think it's an expensive task. How can I get only one User/Uid from Realtime Database?

This is what I came up with (But don't think is the best way):

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

Query emailQuery = usersRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(client.getEmail());

emailQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {

            if (child.getValue(User.class).getEmail().equals(client.getEmail())){

                User user = child.getValue(User.class);
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

Comment: To understand better, you have the UID of the user and you want to get the corresponding details?

Comment: No Alex, it's the other way. I have the corresponding details of each user (email, name), and I want to get the uid of one user (no mather which one)

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your last comment:

> I have the corresponding details of each user (email, name), and I want to get the UID of one user (no matter which one)

To get a particular user from the database based on a particular email address, the query that you are already using:

```
Query emailQuery = usersRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(client.getEmail());
```

Returns only the users who have the field `email` set to what `client.getEmail()` returns. For instance, if `client.getEmail()` returns tedo@gmail.com then you'll get a single result, according to your screenshot, which is the first one. That being said, the following if statement, doesn't make sense to be used:

```
if (child.getValue(User.class).getEmail().equals(client.getEmail())){
    User user = child.getValue(User.class);
}
```

Since the key of the user node is represented by the UID, then you should get it like this:

```
Query emailQuery = usersRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(client.getEmail());
emailQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            User user = child.getValue(User.class);
            String uid = child.getKey();

            //Do what you need to do with UID.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        Log.d("TAG", error.getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
    }
});
```

That's the simplest, cheapest way to query the Realtime Database, in which you return only the elements that you are interested in and that satisfy a particular condition.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly even without if statement :). I'm just newbie and always consider what is a good or bad practice to do.